# How to get different style in nested element depending to depth level?

Tags: html, css, styles, nested

i have nested element and i want that every level have different style

level 1, 5, 9, 13 ... (4n+1) style1

level 2, 6, 10, 14... (4n+2) style2

level 3, 7, 11, 17... (4n+3) style3

level 4, 8, 12, 18... (4n+3) style4

[view exemples](http://jsfiddle.net/UBJUB/)

how to get the 3rd exemple style without using many class when i have infinity level of nested ul

html

```
enter code here
        <div id="content">
    <h1>Exemple 1 neighbor ul and nth-child(an+b) pseudo class</h1>
    <div class="exemple">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li> item 1 1st ul</li>
    <li> item 2 1st ul</li>
    <li> item 3 1st ul</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li> item 1 2nd ul</li>
    <li> item 2 2nd ul</li>
    <li> item 3 2nd ul</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li> item 1 3rd ul</li>
    <li> item 2 3rd ul</li>
    <li> item 3 3rd ul</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li> item 1 4th ul</li>
    <li> item 2 4th ul</li>
    <li> item 3 4th ul</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <h1>Exemple 2 nested ul and nth-child(an+b) pseudo class</h1>
    <div class="exemple">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li> item 1 1st ul

            <ul class="clearfix">
            <li> item 1 2nd ul

                    <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li> item 1 3rd ul</li>
                    <li> item 2 3rd ul</li>
                    <li> item 3 3rd ul

                        <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li> item 1 4th ul</li>
                        <li> item 2 4th ul</li>
                        <li> item 3 4th ul</li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    </ul>

            </li>
            <li> item 2 2nd ul</li>
            <li> item 3 2nd ul</li>
            </ul>

    </li>
    <li> item 2 1st ul</li>
    <li> item 3 1st ul</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <h1>Exemple 3 nested ul and 4 class for different colors</h1>
    <div id="exemple3">
    <ul class="clearfix level1">
    <li> item 1 1st ul

            <ul class="clearfix level2">
            <li> item 1 2nd ul

                    <ul class="clearfix level3">
                    <li> item 1 3rd ul</li>
                    <li> item 2 3rd ul</li>
                    <li> item 3 3rd ul

                        <ul class="clearfix level4">
                        <li> item 1 4th ul</li>
                        <li> item 2 4th ul</li>
                        <li> item 3 4th ul</li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    </ul>

            </li>
            <li> item 2 2nd ul</li>
            <li> item 3 2nd ul</li>
            </ul>

    </li>
    <li> item 2 1st ul</li>
    <li> item 3 1st ul</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
enter code here
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }  
    .clearfix:after { clear: both; }  
    .clearfix { zoom: 1; }  
    #content{
        width:500px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    h1{text-align:center; font-size:2em;}
    ul {list-style: none; padding:10px; margin:10px;}
    ul li {color:#fff; float:left; margin:10px 30px; position:relative; white-space:nowrap;}
    ul ul { position:absolute; top:31px; left:-50px}
    ul ul ul { position:absolute; top:10px; left:116px}
    .exemple ul:nth-child(4n+1) { background: navy; }
    .exemple ul:nth-child(4n+2) { background: green; }
    .exemple ul:nth-child(4n+3) { background: maroon; }
    .exemple ul:nth-child(4n+4) { background: purple; }

    #exemple3 .level1 { background: navy; }
    #exemple3 .level2 { background: green; }
    #exemple3 .level3 { background: maroon; }
    #exemple3 .level4 { background: purple; }
```

Comment: can i have the 3rd exemple (different background) without using 4 classe. i want to use something like nth-child() http://jsfiddle.net/UBJUB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is this the best way:

```
function style(obj,depth){  
    switch (depth%6) {  
      case (0):  
         obj.addClass('level1');  
         break;  
      case (1):  
         obj.addClass('level2');  
         break;  
      case (2):  
         obj.addClass('level3');  
         break;  
      case (3):  
         obj.addClass('level4');  
         break;  
      case (4):  
         obj.addClass('level5');  
         break;  
      case (5):  
         obj.addClass('level6');  
         break;  
      }  
   }  

function color(nav){  
    $ul=nav.find('ul');  
    $ul.each(function(){  
        style($(this),$(this).parents("ul").length);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is doable without classes (or JavaScript), as in your third example. Both nth-child() and nth-of-type() work by selecting siblings elements - that is, elements that have the same direct parent element.

The issue you are running in to is that the nested <ul>s are not siblings to each other, they are descendants, so the count resets for each one.

I cannot think of a way to solve this for an infinite level of <ul>s without either reworking the structure completely, or if this isn't an option, using JavaScript.